# Can I add a separator <li> after the anchor tag In Wordpress wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: wordpress

I need to add `<li>` separator after the anchor tag like this:

```
   <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="services">Services</a></li>
<li class="separator>//</li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>  
<li class="separator>//</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a couple of different ways. [Check the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_men), but the following $arg's will help.

> > $before
> >         (string) (optional) Output text before the  of the link
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $after
>       (string) (optional) Output text after the  of the link
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $link_before
>       (string) (optional) Output text before the link text
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $link_after
>       (string) (optional) Output text after the link text
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```

Try

```
$args = array('after'=>'<li>//</li>');
wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Comment: but i dont need to link this //, i need to this separator is a separate li tag

Comment: okay, I have edited it to do this. If you need to remove the last one, I would add a class to the <li> element and utilise CSS's last-child pseudo class.

Comment: Unfortunately this will affect the submenus... Div with .submenu will be added OUTSIDE the LI's and this will result in a bad functioning of the menu's submenu part.

Comment: It can be solved by extending the default "Walker_Nav_Menu" wp function, adding the .sep class before every li, when required the first .sep li can have through jQuery also a .first class and the sep will be eliminated, the description_walker() need to be called in the arguments of the wordpress menu. if is needed, i can write detailed explanations in an answer, just open the question and link to it and invite me to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is and old question but I stumble upon the same problem and solved it using a custom Walker.

First the walker adds a separator after each `<li>` on the top level:

```
class Main_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";

        if ($depth == 0)
            $output .="<li class='separator'>|</li>\n";        
    }
}
```

Then you can use `li:last-child` and hide the last separator or use a filter and remove it if you need ie7 support. Here's my filter:

```
function menu_remove_last_separator($items){

    $separator = "<li class='separator'>|</li>";
    $pos = strrpos($items, $separator);

    if ($pos) 
        $items = substr_replace($items, '', $pos, strlen($separator));

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','menu_remove_last_separator');
```

Now you must use your walker as and argument for `wp_nav_menu`:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'navigation',
        'container'      => false,
        'menu_class'     => 'inline',
        'walker'         => new main_menu_walker()
        )
);
```